# Dependency is not satisfiable: libtiff4 when trying to install Lightworks on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, libtiff, lightworks

I was trying to install Lightworks 11.5.1 (amd64) on Ubuntu 14.04(amd64) but there's a notice: Dependency is not satisfiable: libtiff4.
Is there anyway to solve this dependency issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lightworks 11.5.1 is only compatible with Ubuntu 13.10, see the following specs:

http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=118&tmpl=component

14.04 provides [libtiff5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libtiff5) but not [libtiff4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libtiff4) (up to saucy 13.10).

To install the 13.10 amd64 version, go to the download [page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/) and select  [`libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb).

Now open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type in the folder where you downloaded the deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then try again to open `lwks-11.5.1-amd64.deb` with the Software Center to continue the installation.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer with a way to install libtiff4

Comment: Couldn't find the old libtiff4 download now, looks like it is no longer there.

Comment: @matt I've updated the download link (to use http://old-releases.ubuntu.com instead)

Comment: Gee thanks :) Is this workaround really safe? I guess this will overwrite libtiff5's files right?

Comment: @matt Both are co-installable, libtiff5 will install `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5` and libtiff4 `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Per [this sticky](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=21&id=68998&Itemid=81) on the Lightworks forum, this bug has been fixed in the latest beta release 11.5.2a, which you can download from the [downloads page](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_lwks&view=download&Itemid=206#).

[image]

For more information see [the changelog](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_lwks&view=changelog&id=128&Itemid=207).

If you prefer to use the stable version [Sylvain's answer works](https://askubuntu.com/a/449594/44179).

Comment: I seem to be unable to download the beta version. All I get when I click on the provided link is a form to sign up for their website. The links for stable versions work fine though

Comment: @byf-ferdy It looks like you're right, you do have to sign in. However, since you need to do that anyway, before using the application I guess it doesn't matter much.