# Cannot install Canon MG6350 drivers - libtiff4 is not installed - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, canon, libtiff

I am having problems installing my Canon MG6350 multifunction printer drivers on Ubuntu 14.04. When I run the install.sh in terminal I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNLDD.png) that libtiff4 is not installed. Ubuntu 14.04 has libtiff5. These drivers where made to be compatible with Ubuntu 12.04. How can I fix my problem ? Installing old libtiff4, would work for me ? If so, how ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I got the same problem but when installing MG 3210 with Ubuntu 14.04, it seems that version of libtiff (actually libtiff5) is not compatible with the drivers, however, I am not sure if it is possible to force the driver to look for libtiff5 instead of libtiff4

Comment: Problems with the Canon driver should be reported to sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency is not satisfiable: libtiff4 when trying to install Lightworks on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449571/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-libtiff4-when-trying-to-install-lightworks-on-ubu)

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this problem while trying to install drivers for my ip3600 on 14.04, alongside a libcupsys2 dependancy.  This is the best descripton of how to solve it: http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/linux-ubuntu-10-04-driver-for-canon-ip3600-ij-printer

Although it only describes how to change the libcupsys2 issue, it's the same method for libtiff4.  Your basically changing the code in the driver to look for libtiff5, not libtiff4.

Seems to have got me up and running.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I can confirm that this works for the Canon PIXMA MG2200 driver on Ubuntu 20.04, in case this is helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and hacked a solution. Feel free to try it.

1) Install libtiff4 from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/libtiff4/download)

1a) I'm on amd64, which clashed with an already installed libtiff4:i386, which I removed:

```
sudo apt-get remove libtiff4:i386
```

then,

```
sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

[I didn't bother checking to see what depended on libtiff4:i386 on my system, so do this at your own risk. I was feeling brave/reckless]

2) Installed the canon driver from [here](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100469202.html), and executed install.sh

It is disappointing that there hasn't been an update to this driver since 2012.

Printer options for the official driver are scarce but the quality is fairly decent. I couldn't get the default CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10-pre2 driver to work at all. However, I have kept it installed as it does show the ink level, which is handy.

### Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A little more googling led me to this - [Easily modify dependencies of a .deb file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724)  - a bash script allowing you to vi edit the control file.

About five minutes work and I had the driver installed.

Comment: Even if you link only to ubuntuforums.org, it still would be better if you provide the script and steps here and use the link only to give credit to the source. Even there contents and links can change and then your answer would be a dead end.