# Can I install libpoppler-dev on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, libraries

It appears as per `apt`, that `libpoppler-dev` depends on `libpoppler46`, which depends on `libtiff4`. `libtiff4` cannot be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 (which already has `libtiff5` in my case).

Can you suggest a solution?

Older related questions' answers suggested hacking a manual install of libtiff4 from Ubuntu 13 downloads that are not even available by now.

Answer (score 1):

As per the updated answer on [Dependency is not satisfiable: libtiff4 when trying to install Lightworks on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449571/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-libtiff4-when-trying-to-install-lightworks-on-ubu/449594?noredirect=1#comment885310_449594) - you can install libtiff4 by hand, and then `libpoppler-dev` simply installs with apt-get. Hopefully `libtiff5` still works as mentioned there...