# Is reinstalling apt-get safe to do [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies

The original problem is that I can't install new apps because of problem of unmet dependecies.
I have tried almost all the solutions in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa), and non of them worked, so I am completely desperate!

Is there is a 100% guaranteed method to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, there is a "100% guaranteed method" called "backup and reinstall".

Comment: reinstall what ? apt? @mikewhatever

Comment: Why should you reinstall apt? Solve your dependencies!

Comment: how can I solve dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449571/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-libtiff4-when-trying-to-install-lightworks-on-ubu) --please complete reading before going to the link.
I traked the dependencies untill I found that there is only one package apt can't resolve "libtiff4" so I downloaded and installed it manually.
thanks to [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander)